# Detect when any part of component tree has changed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, `Parent` and `Child`:

```
function Child() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => setCounter(counter + 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);  
  }, [counter, setCounter]);

  return <div>{counter}</div>;
}

function Parent() {
  return <Child />;
}
```

`Child` is just a simple timer that increments/renders a counter.

From `Parent` (*i.e.* my root component), how can I know when **any part** of the component tree has changed? For example, when `Child` updates its state and re-renders?

Passing a callback to `Child` is not a solution, because in a real app, I would have hundreds of children, and I need to know any time **any part** of the component tree changes.

I tried using `useEffect`/`componentDidUpdate` in `Parent`, but that doesn't get called when a child managing its own state re-renders. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Redux use case. You can achieve this easily on redux.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? As far as I understand, Redux is a store of state. The counter was just an example -- what I need to know is not so much when state has changed, but when the virtual DOM has changed. Using Redux to solve this would force me to put *all* of my state in Redux, even when local state is more suitable.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to reflect your true intention of knowing when the virtual DOM of a component tree has changed.

Comment: Hi @LisaBaier, if you use Redux/ContextAPI, you will be able to find the changes on state and virtual DOM, because virtual DOM and states are two way bindings. Any changes occurred to state that will trigger re-render to virtual DOM. if you will use local state, then you  will face prop drilling issue, because you need to pass props to all levels of your nested component. Please do let me know, if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should try doing is have each component be able to know if the current render cycle will cause a DOM change, based on whatever props or state have changed. Then call a function provided through [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (a provider in the component that wants to know about the changes, a subscriber in each child) to let the parent know a change has happened. You can call this function in a `useEffect` so that it happens after the DOM changes.